# Count the number of same coloured pixel in a labelled object in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-segmentation

I am trying to segment an image of rocks and I get a decent result. But now I need to count the pixels in the largest colored object. 
[image: Segmented image]

The picture above shows a segmented image of a rock pile and I want to count the number of green pixels which denote the largest rock in the image. And then also count the 2nd largest,i.e, the yellow one. After counting I would like to compare it with the ground truth to compare my results.

The code to get the segmented image is referred from [Watershed segmentation opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html). A part of my code is also given below :

```
  cv::findContours(peaks_8u, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

  // Create the marker image for the watershed algorithm
  // CV_32S - 32-bit signed integers ( -2147483648..2147483647 )
  cv::Mat markers = cv::Mat::zeros(input_image.size(), CV_32S);
  // Draw the foreground markers
  for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
  {
    cv::drawContours(markers, contours, static_cast<int>(i), cv::Scalar(static_cast<int>(i) + 1), -1);
  }

  // Draw the background marker
  cv::circle(markers, cv::Point(5, 5), 3, cv::Scalar(255), -1);



  cv::watershed(in_sharpened_image, markers);



  // Generate random colors; result of watershed
  std::vector<cv::Vec3b> colors;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
  {
    int b = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 256); //0,256
    int g = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 256);
    int r = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 256);
    colors.push_back(cv::Vec3b((uchar)b, (uchar)g, (uchar)r));
  }

  // Create the result image
  cv::Mat dst = cv::Mat::zeros(markers.size(), CV_8UC3);
  // Fill labeled objects with random colors
  for (int i = 0; i < markers.rows; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < markers.cols; j++)
    {
      int index = markers.at<int>(i, j);
      if (index > 0 && index <= static_cast<int>(contours.size()))
      {
        dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = colors[index - 1];
      }
    }
  }
```

Question: Is there an efficient way to count the pixels inside the largest/marker in opencv?

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate a histogram of `markers` using cv::calcHist with range from `0` to `contours.size() + 1` and find the largest value in it starting from the index `1`.

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Comment: I will try this method. Thanks. Can you provide a sample code?

Comment: @VOM This is the only a couple lines of code, using calcHist() just like in all those examples or tutorials. Easy to try without examples.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counting pixels you could use contourArea() for your largest contour. This will work much faster.

Something like this.

```
    cv::Mat mask;

    // numOfSegments - number of your labels (colors)
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfSegments; i++) {
                std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

                // this "i + 2" may be different for you
                // depends on your labels allocation.
                // This is thresholding to get mask with
                // contour of your @i label (color)
                cv::inRange(markers, i + 2, i + 2, mask);

                contours.clear();
                findContours(mask, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

                double area = cv::contourArea(contours[0]);
    }
```

Having contours in hands is also good because after watershed() they will be quite "noisy" with lots of small peaks and not suitable for most of using in the "raw" form. Having contour you may smooth it with gauss or approxPoly, etc., as well as check for some important properties or contour shape if you need it.

Comment: will try this way too.